# Record SSH terminal in linux

Tags: linux, ssh, shell, recording

I am configuring a Bastion Host

Jump Server

I'm trying to record SSH terminals in the server automatically, I'm using `TermRecord`. The problem starts when I add `TermRecord -o ss.html` to my `.bashrc`:

```
echo "TermRecord -o ss.html" >> ~/.bashrc
```

The terminal will flood "script started" without saving anything.

Answer (score 2):

I have absolutely no experience with `TermRecord`, my answer is based on a reasonable (I hope so) guess about what happens.

It *looks* like `TermRecord` sources `.bashrc` again, or more likely it runs another `bash` that sources the file. *I assume the latter*. Anyway it runs `TermRecord` again, yet another `bash` sources `.bashrc` again and so on.

If this stops you from logging in, see [*Login without running `bash_profile` or `bashrc`*](https://serverfault.com/q/94503). I would try `ssh -t username@hostname /bin/sh` and fix my `.bashrc` from there.

To make it work as you expected you need to find a way to suppress executing `TermRecord` if already inside `TermRecord`. The best way would be if the program added some variable to the environment, so you could detect it. I cannot find whether or not it sets any variable.

In case it doesn't, you can do this by yourself. Instead of

```
TermRecord -o ss.html
```

in your `.bashrc` use something like this:

```
[ -z "$TR_PPID" ] && { export TR_PPID=$$; TermRecord -o ss.html; }
```

It means: if the variable is empty, set it to the shell PID and run `TermRecord`; otherwise do nothing (continue to the next line).

Notes:

- Make sure the variable named `TR_PPID` is not used by `TermRecord` or anything else. I made this name up (from "TermRecord parend PID"), there may be a collision though.
- Hardcoded `-o ss.html` may cause trouble if you log in multiple times.
- If `TermRecord` gets executed then the rest of `.bashrc` will be sourced by the outer `bash` as late as `TermRecord` exits. The inner `bash` will source the file on its own.
- To avoid nesting processes, you may consider replacing the outer `bash` with `TermRecord` instead of creating a separate process; it can be done with `exec TermRecord -o ss.html`. In this case you probably want the whole line to be at the very beginning of your `.bashrc`. Now the variable would mean "TermRecord PID" so `TR_PID` would be a better name.

---

Possible(?) alternative: use `TermRecord` as your login shell.

- Only if it supports being a login shell (I don't know this); otherwise it may cause trouble (but maybe a custom wrapper would fix it). Experiments with changing your login shell (see `chsh`) should be performed without leaving the old shell or even with an extra "emergency shell". If you by any means lock yourself out and cannot log in anew, you still have the old shell running and you can fix it.
- This may require editing `/etc/shells`.
- In this case you shouldn't start `TermRecord` from your `.bashrc` at all.

Answer (score 0):

As I understand it, you wish to record all your terminal stdin/stdout while ssh'd to a server?

consider using  **script** command

```
script <output_filename>
```

and then ssh to your server, once you are done close your ssh connection and

```
exit
```

to stop the script recording, the $output_filename you provided will be in your current directory.

ps: you could make sure your recordings are always named uniquely by using the following convention

```
script foo_$(date  +"%Y-%m-%d%H%M")   # full date and time included in filename
```

or

```
script foo_$(date +%s)  # unique number calculate by seconds since the Unix epoch
```